# Textbox value into trackbar

Tags: .net, vb.net, textbox, trackbar

I have a question.
I have been doing VB Express 2015 in class for over three months now.
If you place a trackbar and a textbox in a form, you can display the value of the trackbar in the textbox.

Can you make it so that it goes the other way around? That if you type a value into the textbox, it applies to the position of the slider?

(I have been trying and searching for two afternoons, haven't found a direct solution and its irritating me to death. Every teacher doesn't know, I just want to know how to solve this problem.)

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do it:

```
Private Sub TextBox_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    Dim value As Integer
    If Int32.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, value) Then
        TrackBar1.Value = value
    Else
        'something was entered into the textbox that is not an integer
    End If
End Sub
```

When the contents of the textbox changes we try and see if the value entered is an Integer. If it is we set the TrackBar value to this value

Comment: I found the solution by using the Try,Catch method. Works now.

Answer (score 0):

This was the code if you are interested

```
 Private Sub TextBox_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox.TextChanged
    Try
        TrackBar.Value = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox.Text)
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
    TrackBar_Scroll(sender, e)
End Sub
```